# Consul : Health Check is failed to invoke: fork/exec but running manualy

Tags: ubuntu, consul, hashicorp-vault

I run this command

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin ping --host=192.168.56.35 --port=6033 --user=root --password=123
```

and it says

```
mysqld is alive
```

but when I added it in heallth check

```
   "check": {
     "args": ["/usr/bin/mysqladmin ping --host=192.168.56.35 --port=6033 --user=root password=123"],
     "interval": "3s"}
   }
```

the log says

```
[ERR] agent: Check "service:proxy2" failed to invoke: fork/exec /usr/bin/mysqladmin ping --host=192.168.56.35 --port=6033 --user=root password=123: no such file or directory
```

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"args"` - should be an array of strings. Consul sees your single string as a command to execute, ignoring spaces.

Your check should look something like this:

```
   "check": {
     "args": ["/usr/bin/mysqladmin", "ping", "--host=192.168.56.35", "--port=6033", "--user=root", "password=123"],
     "interval": "3s"}
   }
```

Optionally you can use following instead, since string is passed to `/bin/sh` it doesn't have to be divided into substrings. (most examples in for Consul Checks use this syntax, so it should definitively work):

```
   "check": {
     "args": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/mysqladmin ping --host=192.168.56.35 --port=6033 --user=root password=123"],
     "interval": "3s"}
   }
```

Also make sure that user under which Consul agent process is running is able to execute `/usr/bin/mysqladmin` otherwise you will get permission denied error.